# How to remove non-significant interaction(s) from meta-regression (rma) model

Tags: r, interaction, meta-analysis, regression-strategies, meta-regression

According to the rule of marginality, I should **remove all non-significant interactions** from model to achive simplicity (MInimal Adequate Model).

I am familiar with removing such interactions from **simple linear models in R**.

For example if the triple interaction will be non-significant in model below...

```
m1 <- lm(variable ~ factor_A * factor_B * factor_C)
factor_A                    ***
factor_B                    ***
factor_C                    ***
factor_A:factor_B           **
factor_A:factor_C           **
factor_B:factor_C           *
factor_A:factor_B:factor_C  NS
```

I am able to remove it with `update`:

```
m2 <- update(m1, ~.-factor_A:factor_B:factor_C)
```

However, I have a problem with removing non-significant interaction from **rma model** (moderators included).

```
library(metafor)
my.rma_1 <- rma(yi, vi, mods = ~ factor_A*factor_B*factor_C, data = my.data)
```

Suppose that table of significance is similar to table from lm above.
Such solution by `update` do not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
my.rma_2 <- update(my.rma_1, ~.-factor_A:factor_B:factor_C)
```

Comment: For the record: what the marginality principle does say is not to include higher-order interactions without including the lower-order interactions or main effects involved in them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule of marginality makes no such requirement, and the probability that P-values will tell you the "right" interactions to remove is virtually zero.  Removing non-significant terms from models biases every aspect of the model.  However, when one judges a large set of interaction terms (e.g., all three-way interactions, with a total of 10 d.f.) and the P-value for the entire chunk is > 0.3, one can exclude the entire chunk without paying a large price for model uncertainty.  It is the consideration of individual interaction terms that causes the most damage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @FrankHarrell. So your recommendation is to keep all interactions (including non-significant) inside the model. And present my results in the form of "Full model"?

Comment: Yes, unless you can test entire blocks of variables and remove a whole block when P is very large.